# Efficiently add single row to Pandas Series or DataFrame

Tags: python, performance, pandas, time-series

I want to use Pandas to work with series in real-time. Every second, I need to add the latest observation to an existing series. My series are grouped into a DataFrame and stored in an HDF5 file.

Here's how I do it at the moment:

```
>> existing_series = Series([7,13,97], [0,1,2]) 
>> updated_series = existing_series.append( Series([111], [3]) )
```

Is this the most efficient way? I've read countless posts but cannot find any that focuses on efficiency with high-frequency data.

**Edit**: I just read about modules shelve and pickle. It seems like they would achieve what I'm trying to do, basically save lists on disks. Because my lists are large, is there any way not to load the full list into memory but, rather, efficiently append values one at a time?

Comment: That's probably as efficient as any, but Pandas/numpy structures are fundamentally not suited for efficiently growing.  They work best when they are created with a fixed size and stay that way.

Comment: `append` is a wrapper for `concat`, so `concat` would be marginally more efficient, but as @BrenBarn says Pandas is probably not appropriate for updating a HDF5 file every second. If you absolutely need Pandas for some reason, could you collect a list of Series and update the file periodically instead?

Comment: Bren is right about numpy/pandas working best when preallocated. If memory is no constraint just preallocate a huge zeros array and append at the end of the program removing any excess zeros. Which I suppose is a bit of what Matti is saying.

Comment: Understood, makes sense. Is there a lib you can think of that would be better suited for efficiently growing series?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the new PyTables docs in 0.10 (coming soon) or you can get from master. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html

PyTables is actually pretty good at appending, and writing to a HDFStore every second will work. You want to store a DataFrame table. You can then select data in a query like fashion, e.g.

```
store.append('df', the_latest_df)
store.append('df', the_latest_df)
....
store.select('df', [ 'index>12:00:01' ])
```

If this is all from the same process, then this will work great. If you have a writer process and then another process is reading, this is a little tricky (but will work correctly depending on what you are doing).

Another option is to use messaging to transmit from one process to another (and then append in memory), this avoids the serialization issue.